# How to connect in latest firebse version?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vite

This is my firebase `config.js` file.

When I run the program it won't run with error msg : `"import firebase from "/node_modules/.vite/firebase_app.js?v=46ca94a2";`

It only worked when replaced *firebase* with older version (8.x.x)
but I got several vulnerabilities in my log.

Can anyone point out the problem , I want to use latest version if possible?

I checked the documentation but i found nothing is different from my code
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore'
import "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  ....
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp
const projectAuth = firebase.auth()

export {projectFirestore,timestamp,projectAuth}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that changed with Firebase 9, a reference guide is available here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

I cannot list all the changes here because there is quite a few and it depends on what/how you're already using it right now and which one you want to use later on (`compat` or `modular`).

But mainly, you will need to write the imports like this now

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
```

The whole changelogs are [available here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_900_-_august_25_2021).