# Elements not rendering inside template tag

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

Why are the elements inside the template tag not showing up?

```js
<script setup>
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const auth = getAuth()
const user = ref(null)

watch(() => {
if (auth.currentUser) {
user.value = auth.currentUser
}
})

//display user name
console.log(user.value?.displayName)
</script>

<template>
 <div>
        
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<main>
<h2>{{ user.value?.displayName }}</h2>
</main>
 </div>
</template>
```

The user name appears in the console.

I'm getting this error when I refresh the page:

```
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
```

Comment: The error speaks for itself. You have not initialized the firebase app yet

Comment: Yes. But I initialized in my firebase.config.js

Comment: I don't use Firebase so I can't tell you what exactly to do. But the problem obviously comes from Firebase, not Vue. So you can focus on debugging it. If you can reproduce your problem on an online tool like stackblitz, I and other devs can help you to debug

Comment: Tried that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501815/8816585 ? Mainly the fact that the API have probably changed a bit and you're writing it in the old way.

Answer (score 0):

In you firebaseconfig.js file.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
const firebaseConfig = {...}
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const fbAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

And then in your component use

```
import { fbAuth } from "firebaseconfig.js"; // path to your firebaseconfig file

if (fbAuth.currentUser) {
  console.log(fbAuth)
}
```

Comment: I got an error: ```Component auth has not been registered yet.```

Comment: When I log (console.log) the auth i got this ```AuthImpl {app: FirebaseAppImpl, heartbeatServiceProvider: Provider, config: {…}, currentUser: UserImpl, emulatorConfig: null, …}```

Comment: My Project in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-iiqfd8?file=pages/login.vue  user: flowers@gmail.com password: ww0011

Comment: I need help with this one!

Comment: I run npm run build and it is working, but when I refresh the page I get the error.